# Alternative(s) for TStringGrid for Delphi Prism

Tags: datagridview, delphi-prism, tstringgrid

Since I am starting to develop under Delphi Prism, I noticed it doesn't have any grid tool similar to TStringGrid tool that you normally see in Delphi 7 and below. Although Delphi Prism has a DataGridView, it doesn't easily lend itself for my purpose. In fact, every time I try to set it up and make it work the way we want it to in our software it simply doesn't work at all. From what I understand DataGridView really wants a database source to display data.

So, I would like to know if there are any alternatives to Delphi TStringGrid for Delphi Prism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx) can work in bound and unbound modes, so you can use th DataGridView control like a TStringGrid for display data without binding to a data source.  check some this link [Creating an Unbound Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s3ce6k8.aspx).

Comment: I see, but looking at it closer I see that it acts more like a database table than a simple string grid. I need to be able update the values and strings in the grid realtime on the fly every few seconds. That's part of the problem for me. Also, it seems you don't have control over mouse clicks. It is either the readonly false or true for the whole grid. I need to be able to control each column independent of each other.